# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: SyntaxError

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

Here is my code

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".main-menu a:contains(\"Access Menu\")")).size()
```

is throwing exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

Same css value is working in jquery i.e. `$(".main-menu a:contains(\"Access Menu\")").size()`

Comment: `:contains()` is not a CSS selector. That DOM exception is being thrown by `querySelectorAll()` which I suspect is what WebDriver is using, bypassing jQuery altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to have your html of your `<a>` ?

Because the `DOM Exception 12` is generally a trouble with your html syntax. Maybe the `jQuery` don't care about but the `WebDriver` throws an exception.

**Edit (after BoltClock intervention):**

There is another solution instead of using the CssSelector, the xpath !

```
"//*[@class='.main-menu']/a[contains(text(),'Access Menu')]"
```

Tell me what's up.

Comment: No, it's a problem with the selector syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't the first part be `//*[@class='main-menu']` instead of `//*[@class='.main-menu']`? Also, using `//*[contains(@class, 'main-menu')]` would be better, as we don't have the DOM, we can't promise `main-menu` is the only class.